# Hard disk not detected after formating to DOS_FAT_32

Tags: macos, filesystems, ntfs, hard-drive, fat32

I have a WD Elements external hard disk. Earlier it was using NTFS file system, which I have formatted to DOS_FAT_32. Now I can't see the hard disk in finder or disk utility.

But when I execute the command `diskutil list`, the the external HD is listed:

```
/dev/disk2 (external, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:     FDisk_partition_scheme                        *1.0 TB     disk2
   1:                 DOS_FAT_32 JAY3                    1.0 TB     disk2s1
```

How do I make the hard disk detect in finder window and be able to store and retrieve files from it?

Answer (score 0):

If you are **absolutely sure** it is `/dev/disk2` **and you have no data on it that you want**, you can overwrite the initial few sectors of the disk with zeroes so that it looks completely uninitialised like this:

```
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/rdisk2 bs=65536 count=1000
```

Yes, I did mean to add the extra `r` in front of `disk2` and **no, nobody should copy and paste this command because it will obliterate disk2 !!!**.

Then unplug and replug the disk and go into `Disk Utility`, select the blank disk and click `Erase` at the top of the `Disk Utility` window and you will be able to format it.